# How to place a UIView above UITableView's section headers?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I tried to place a view on top of my table view. It seems to only cover the cells, but not the section headers. I want it to cover both cells and section headers.

[image]

In my UITableViewController subclass:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIView* veilView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 150.0f)];
    veilView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.5f];
    [self.view addSubview:veilView];
}
```

The section headers are constructed in a typical way:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    CustomTableSectionHeaderView* header = [[CustomTableSectionHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, tableView.frame.size.width, [CustomTableSectionHeaderView height])];
    header.text = [self.displayAlphabet objectAtIndex:section];
    return header;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [CustomTableSectionHeaderView height];
}
```

Comment: Why do you want do this?

Comment: I tried to duplicate your problem, but my veilView did cover the header view. Is your code in a UIViewController or UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by a timing issue. I'm actually loading the data for the table from my server. I placed the overlay view before the server returned the data. When the server did return the data, I reload the table view, causing the section headers to be created on top of the overlay view.

This will solve the issue:

```
// When server returns table data:
[self.tableView reloadTable];
[self.veilView.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.veilView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `zPosition` of the view after you create it.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIView* veilView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 150.0f)];
    veilView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.5f];
    [self.view addSubview:veilView];
    [self.addressTextView.layer setZPosition:1000]
}
```

Higher numbers are on top of other views, and the scale is arbitrary, so you can go as high as you like. The default value is 0, but section headers will have a higher value than that as they float over the cells they refer to when you're scrolling.